# compare 2 tables in hbase and write summary to the third table using TableMapReduceUtil

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, elastic-map-reduce

I need to use MR on Hbase to compare 2 tables table1, table2) in hbase and write summary to the third table ( table3)

I am using the below TableMapReduceUtil psuedo code. 
Mapper: Table1
Reducer: Table3.

In mapper, I need to compare Table1 value with Table2.  where do i instantiate Table2?

In the mapper, Do i have to instantiate Table3 for each mapper? I would like to instantiate  Table3
only once for the entire MapReduce job?

```
driver()
{
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
    table1,        // input table
    scan,              
    MyMapper.class,     // mapper class
    Text.class,         
    IntWritable.class,  
    job);
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
    table3,        // output table
    MyTableReducer.class,    
    job);
}


public static class MyMapper extends TableMapper<Text, IntWritable>  {
    public static final byte[] CF = "cf".getBytes();
    public static final byte[] ATTR1 = "attr1".getBytes();

    private final IntWritable ONE = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text text = new Text();

    public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String val = new String(value.getValue(CF, ATTR1));
            String diff;
            //instantiate Table3 and compare with val. Do i have to instantiate for each mapper?

            text.set(diff);     

            context.write(text, ONE);
    }
}


public static class MyTableReducer extends TableReducer<Text, IntWritable, ImmutableBytesWritable>  {
    public static final byte[] CF = "cf".getBytes();
    public static final byte[] COUNT = "count".getBytes();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int i = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                i += val.get();
            }
            Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(key.toString()));
            put.add(CF, COUNT, Bytes.toBytes(i));

            context.write(null, put);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to create a table in HBase that's already been created, it will throw a TableExistsException that you can choose to ignore. See [HBaseAdmin docs](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#createTable(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor)). So you're OK - the first mapper to create the table will actually create it, and then the others will throw the exception which you will ignore.